# iphone application with multiple views

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Iam trying to develop an iphone app having tab view as the base, within the tabs would be table view which would list the nodes/devices. When a particular node is clicked in the table view, more information related to that particular node should be displayed(in next view). Which type of application i.e view based, navigation/window based project should i choose and can u point me to some tutorial which can help me accomplish my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tabbed application template in the iOS application templates when you create a new project from the file menu.

And here's a tutorial link:

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/45161

Comment: I am using xcode 3 , which does not have the template u mentioned.I tried to get xcode 4 but some issues came up and i had to settle down using 3 only

Comment: I have XCode 3 and it has a tab bar template.  See this youtube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFNtD098Bbk  Are you sure you have the latest version of XCode 3?

Comment: it shows xcode 3.2.. how do i upgrade to latest version..

Comment: Log into http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action and you can get it there.

Comment: well iam unable to do that.. May we have to find out the similar solution but for the XCODE 3.2.. Phew.. somebody help me out..

Comment: You could do it programmatically:  Here's a link to sampel code: http://www.myfirstiphoneapplication.com/2009/11/tabbar-together-with-a-navbar-programmatically/  The source is available at the bottom of the page.

Comment: But i have forgot the basic thing, what type of project should i begin    with?? view/window/navigation.. I am very new to iphone dev, cant figure this out easily..

Comment: I would say try the Single View application, but if you're that new you really should get a good book on development and follow the tutorials over the course of a week or two.  It will save you a TON of headaches.  Jeff LaMarche makes some great iOS tutorial books.